# Why animation "Height" property doesn't work for Windows Universal App in the same way as "Opacity" property?

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, win-universal-app, rectangles

Using following code :

```
        Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = From;
        doubleAnimation.To = To;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, seconds, miliseconds));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, Target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, FrameworkElemProperty);
        storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        storyBoard.Completed += storyBoard_Completed;
        storyBoard.Begin();
```

Works excellent for the "Opacity" as the FrameworkElemProperty, but doesn't work in case of Rectangle, when I try to animate "Height"/"Width" property. Does someone know what's going on here ? Is there any problem on Microsoft Framework side or will this require any magic addition ? (Opacity and Height are the same properties of the FrameworkElement so it's expected this will behave in the same way) Worked perfectly in Silverlight..

Answer (score 5):

This is documented behavior. See [Optimize animations, media, and images](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204774.aspx) on MSDN.

Opacity is an "Independant Animation" which doesn't depend on or affect other properties or other objects. It can run wholly on the composition thread and can run efficiently and smoothly.

Height is a "Dependent Animation" which will force the overall layout to update when changed. This requires syncing the composition thread and the UI thread and can lead to slow and inefficient rendering.

Dependent Animations are disabled by default and should be avoided whenever possible. Height and Width are the specific examples given in the documentation, and they can often be replaced by independantly animating the RenderTransform instead of altering the layout.

If an app needs to use a dependent animation then it can enable them by setting the animation's [EnableDependentAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx) property to true and the overall [Timeline.AllowDependentAnimations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.allowdependentanimations.aspx) to true.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the answer! Let me check and play with that what you've described. Complaining, as that was quite straight forward in Silverlight(MS best framework I've seen so far among others).. and now we port our solutions to Uni App and see some blocking spots here and there. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Tested as OK! EnableDependentAnimation = true in Animation was a best approach for us in this case, as we only init our controls by this and we require Width and Height parameters as an input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height value but you can not animate it, I is not designed for that. If you want an animation with the height you should consider animate the **ScaleTransoform.ScaleY** property.

```
<[YourFrameworkElement].RenderTransform>
  <ScaleTransform x:Name="Target" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.5"/>
</[YourFrameworkElement].RenderTransform>
```

Comment: This solution is OK. EnableDependentAnimation = true for the Animation object also works, but draws more CPU, as a dependant animation.